# Non Max Suppression settings and postprocessing for EfficientDet

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I've downloaded and installed the Tensorflow Object Detection API and downloaded one of the [EfficientDet models.](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/efficientdet/d7/1) As I want to do some work on the raw scores directly before Non-Max Suppression reduces it to class output, my first goal was to try and get the same final outputs from the raw scores, using the downloaded model config as a guide.

```
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 9.99999993922529e-09
        iou_threshold: 0.5
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
```

As the Object Detection API has no score converter method under postprocessing, I'm not sure what this does, but the only batch NMS method in utils seems to be `batch_multiclass_non_max_suppression`.

So, having fed an image into the network and got an output detections, to try and replicate its results:

```
    result = post_processing.batch_multiclass_non_max_suppression(tf.expand_dims(detections['raw_detection_boxes'], 2), detections['raw_detection_scores'], 9.99999993922529e-09, 0.5, 100, max_total_size=100)
    detections['detection_boxes'] = result[0]
    detections['detection_scores'] = result[1]
    detections['detection_classes'] = result[2]
```

i.e., substitute the relevant scores in the detections with the output of NMS, and insert the dimension needed for the batch function to work. This is then visualised following [per the TensorFlow Hub colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/colab/tf2_object_detection.ipynb).

The problem is that whilst the input image (this from the MSCOCO dataset) should produce this:
[image: Correct output]

It instead produces this:

[image: Incorrect output]

The bounding boxes are all (seemingly) shifted upwards and the categories are simply off, which suggests there's more processing being done between the raw scores, NMS, and output, but it's entirely unclear what. The scores are correct, so it appears to be pruning correctly.

**Edit:** I suspect, after looking at the SSD model template, that the problem with the misaligned bounding boxes is because I'm not passing the resized image dimensions along to NMS, which is generated by the preprocessing step, which should be easy enough to address via generating the image resize function. However, after applying the slice operation to remove a background class doesn't address the incorrect labels:

[image: Different incorrect output]

Instead, it seems to have lost the person class entirely--this makes sense; it isn't configured to include a background class of any sort and if Person (id 1) is instead coming out as index 0, then this would cut them off.

**EDIT 2:** I looked at the original meta-architecture further and copied the image-resizing function, i.e.:

```
from object_detection.protos import image_resizer_pb2
from object_detection.utils import config_util as c
from object_detection.utils import shape_utils

config =  c.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(r"C:\Users\Person\.keras\datasets\efficientdet_d7_coco17_tpu-32\pipeline.config")
image_config = c.get_image_resizer_config(config['model'])
resize = image_resizer_builder.build(image_config)

def compute_clip_window(preprocessed_images, true_image_shapes):
# identical to the meta-arch definition

# image resizing 
im = tf.cast(input_tensor, tf.float32)
channel_offset = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406]
channel_scale = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]
im = ((im / 255.0) - [[channel_offset]]) / [[channel_scale]]
resized = shape_utils.resize_images_and_return_shapes(im, resize)

clip = compute_clip_window(resized[0], resized[1])
```

Therefore allowing the clip argument to be supplied to NMS. However, this doesn't change anything, and it still returns the same mis-aligned boxes as the second image. This is incredibly confusing, as this seems like it should replicate everything the model needs in both the preprocessing and postprocessing steps to generate its own output: the image is normalized and resized; the true image size is retained alongside the resized image; no further processing of the raw boxes or raw scores happens before they get passed to the NMS (the returned versions of the raw values are identical to the values passed to NMS except with one dimension [and the model itself](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/models/ssd_efficientnet_bifpn_feature_extractor.py) doesn't interfere with the post-processing at all--and the call signature calls preprocessing, prediction, and postprocessing in turn, so nothing else should be happening in the interim.

**Edit 3:** I added another line was added (to no effect)--setting the multiclass scores in the NMS additional fields to the detection scores with backgrounds (i.e., the raw scores). By adding +1 to all the label classes, I got the following image:

[image: Slightly more correct output]

Whilst this is correct, this only corrects for the earlier parts of the dataset, i.e. where the only empty class is the 0th. It still appears that there must be some mapping step I'm not following, alongside whatever is causing the image misalignment.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution in my case was to load the model from the checkpoint and configs, rather than use the saved model directly, in order to access the original preprocess, predict, and postprocess methods, rather than having a single function call.